# Loop Object Relationship Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here i'm trying to to loop through all my users with their related assignments. I have made the User->Assignment Relationship in the model. When I dd($students) I receive the array of students with their related assignments, however when I view this on the page I do not receive the loop of assignments. What could I have missed in the code? Im sure it's somewhere in the html I messed up.

**User Model:**

```
public function assignments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Assignment');
}
```

**Assignment Model:**

```
public function userAssignment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$students = User::where('position','student')->with('assignments')->get();
```

**Html:**

```
@foreach($students as $student)
                              <div class="item{{{ $isFirst ? ' active' : '' }}}">
                                  <div class = "deck">
                                    <div class = "row marg">
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                          <div class = "stdnt">
                                            <h1>Student Info</h1>
                                            <h1>{{$student->name}}</h1>
                                            <p>Program: {{$student->pack}}</p>
                                            <p>Level: {{$student->level}}</p>
                                            <p>Status: {{$student->status}}</p>
                                            <p>Lesson: {{$student->lesson}}</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class = "col-md-4">
                                          <div class = "teac">
                                            <h1>Teacher Info</h1>
                                            <h1>{{$student->teacher}}</h1>
                                              <p>Picture</p>
                                              <p>assign form</p>
                                              <p>assign button</p>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                  </div>
                                  <div class = "mask flow">
                                         <div class = "row-fluid marg">
                                           @foreach($student->assignments() as $assignment)
                                                <div class = "ablock">
                                                    <h1>{{$assignment->title}}</h1>
                                                    <p>{{$assignment->created_at}}</p>
                                                    <p>{{$assignment->type}}</p>
                                                    <p>{{$assignment->body}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                           @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                  </div>
                               {{--*/ $isFirst = false; /*--}}
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the `assignments` method. Simply access it as a property:

```
@foreach($student->assignments as $assignment)
    //                       ^^
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yep. That worked. It's the little things..Many thanks Joseph.